# How to wait for status code 200 while using HttpClient class from .Net 4.0 app, invokes another .Net core api, both windows auth enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

I have 2 apps, both windows auth enabled and will be on same server.
**One is client app**(done in .net 4.0) and **other is api**(done in .net core 2.0).
I need to call Api from client app from server side(can't do from ajax due to some unavoidable restrictions from api design).

For this **i am using HttpClient (System.Net.Http v2.0)**, code is as below:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResponse> InvokeGetWithQueryParam<TResponse>(string apiBaseUrl, string getRelativeUrl, Dictionary<string, string> queryParamList)
        {
            var url = GetUriBuilderInstance(apiBaseUrl, getRelativeUrl, queryParamList);
            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true };

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            List<TResponse> responseObj = null;
            try
            {
                //this gives 3 codes 401 twice and 200 at last, i only want next if to execute/process response and give data back when only for 200
                var response = **client.GetAsync**(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    responseObj = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<TResponse>>().Result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                //do logging later
                throw;
            }

            return responseObj;
        }
```

When i run it, i get **3 different error codes in fiddler** as can be seen here.

[image]

> My question is
>
> how can i ensure that this method returns data only when response code
>   is 200?

Any idea will be helpful.

**Note:** 
I can't use async await anyways, as its not .net 4.5, so please avoid suggestions around .net 4.5 or plus versions.

Comment: If you "can't" use `await`, then don't use `HttpClient`, which was specifically designed for `async`/`await`. Use `WebClient` instead.

Comment: implement retry logic , where you keep trying till you get 200

Comment: @stephen clearly - httpclient can be used in .Net 4.5+ or 4.0 with one of usage difference is when used in .4.0,calls can't be awaited. That alone shall not be reason to drop using it and fallback to much older web client. Please enlighten me if what I understand is wrong, and it must only be used when want to await for calls. There are various examples/articles in internet saying it can be used in .Net 4.0 over older web client, following which I tried using and struck at current challenge.

Comment: @shantanu thanks.  assuming by retry you mean to re-run/invoke getasync method, every retry will internally end up giving first 2 responses as non 200, as it's call to service which is negotiating on authentication and first 2 calls(internally done by getasync method itself) fails, and third time it succeeds with 200. It's 3 responses for single getasync calls is what I need to handle, I am afraid retry will not fit. Correct me if I am wrong. Or is there anyway to decipher/understand from fiddler 3 request-response which mode of auth negotiation works and tell httpclient to use that at first.